# Find files with multiline strings matched

Tags: python, perl, sed, awk

I have a folder with many files of such blocks of pattern:

```
115,55
,175:500
,123:400
,[blahblah]
,[blahblah]
...
,[blahblah]
200,*
,[blahblah]
,[blahblah]
,[blahblah]
...
```

Each block starts at a line starting with a number and ends before the next line starting with a number.

I need to find files containing "115,55" and ",123:400" in the same block. There could be any number of lines between the two like:

```
115,55
,[blahblah]
...
,[blahblah]
,123:400
```

Summary: Find the names of files with "115,55" and next having ",123:400" before hitting a line starting with a number.

Note:This is a UDR (Usage Data Record) file if it may help.

Python, Perl, sed or awk would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want to print the filenames or the entire block or both? Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: I just need to print the filenames containing the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -lne '/^115,55/ ... /^\d/ and /^,123:400/ or next;print $ARGV;close ARGV' *udr
```

Comment: `(/^115,55/ .. /^,123:400/) =~ /E/ or next` doesn't work because it will match across blocks.  I believe I've created a fix for that though.  However, can perl work on globs like `*udr`?  I don't know how to do that properly, so could use your advice.

Comment: @Miller shell does the globing and perl works only with `@ARGV`. Btw, your range match starts and stop on the same line.

Comment: That's why I used the `...` range instead of `..`.  So it would not stop and start on the same line.

Comment: I'm so used to working on strawberry perl, I sometimes forget how superior unix environments are.  Dunno if there's a way to get cmd to interpret globs.  hrm :/

Comment: @Miller perhaps `perl -e "BEGIN{ @ARGV=glob pop} " *txt`

Comment: @Miller, the script failed on my system. 

"Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options)."
   
My system is SunOS and Perl version is: "This is perl, v5.8.4 built for sun4-solaris-64int"

Comment: @mpapec Thanks for letting me collaborate with you a bit.  Tiz kinda a fun way to solve a problem.  Btw, can still remove 7 more characters if one cares.  Also, I had also thought of the BEGIN block solution, and didn't think it would work.  However, just confirmed that it does.

Comment: @Miller never thought of using `$1` when matched but undef, tnx. Although `.. and something or next` feels strange somehow.

Comment: It does feel a little strange to trust the left to right nature of logical operators to build an expanded shortcut op.  Kind of makes me want to throw in some `()` or change it to a `next unless`, as I'd never do such a thing in anything but a one liner.  However, I can see using the `.. && $1` idiom in the future.  Only just thought of it for this problem.

Comment: Just realized that the `$1` was actually unnecessary.  Reads more logically now.  `if in block && inner test.`

Comment: @Miller `perl -lne 'print($ARGV),close ARGV if /^115,55/ ... /^\d/ and /^,123:400/'`

Comment: Nice one, I think that's as tight as we can make the code.  Now, if we were good experts, we'd point out that the regexes should be `$` bounded.  And to avoid the edge case of two blocks in sequence (which MIGHT be possible since Yigit was reporting repeated matches to jaypal), we should add a negative lookahead assertion to the end of the range `/^(?!115,55$)\d/`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/115,55/{f=1;next}!/^,/{f=0;next}/,123:400/&&f{print FILENAME;nextfile}' /path/to/files/*
```

Comment: Oh, I have just discovered that it prints the filename for every hit on the file. Any way to break and continue with the next file as it finds one match? This would improve performance and shrink the output.

Comment: @Yiğit The perl solution only prints the filenames once.

Comment: @Yiğit Yes, check the updated solution. `nextfile` breaks out of the current file and moves on the next file.